# How set one grid line visible and others invisible?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I made such a polar axes:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.set_yticks([])
```

the plot drawing as:

[image]

I want to leave only the horizontal line(the line between 0~180）and set other grid lines invisible.

`ax.grid(False)` will set all the lines invisible.How could leave one line visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show only the horizontal line, you can add these two lines, which will set the x-axis line, and show the 0-180 degree line. Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
import math
ax.set_xticks([0,math.pi])
```

[image]